# PUT requests seem to always route to get in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, put

I'm trying to run some tests via rspec, and I keep getting errors for the traffic not being rerouted.  It specifically happens on PUT and DELETE requests.  I'm not getting a routing error, the error is:

`Expected response to be a redirect to http://www.example.com/ but was a redirect to https://www.example.com/users/212`

My UsersController looks somewhat like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy]

  .
  .
  .

  def update
    puts "Update called."

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

and yet "Update called" is never printed when running rspec, but the "Show called" puts in the show method always is.  the signed_in method looks like this:

```
def signed_in_user
  puts "Signed in?: #{signed_in?}"

  if !signed_in?

    store_location
    flash[ :notice ] = "You must sign in to access this page."
    redirect_to signin_url
  end
end
```

"Signed in" is also never printed.

Here is the test that's throwing one of the errors:

```
describe "for non-signed-in users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "in the Users controller" do
    describe "submitting to the update action" do
      before { put user_path(user) }
      specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

My best guess is that the tests aren't respecting the "put" keyword in the before call, but I would have no idea why, or what's going on there. I'm using rails version 3.2.13 and rspec-rails version 2.11.0

**EDIT:** If I insert `puts user` at the beginning of the test statement (but after the let statement), I get an error:

`` undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x007fd4943743d8> ``

Comment: I'm by no means an authority on RSpec but every example I've seen does something more like: `put :update, id: @user, user: { some: "params" }`

Comment: just tried `put :update, id: user.id, user: user`, same error unfortunately

EDIT: Was looking at the wrong error, this gives me a bad argument error. (Expected URI object or URI string)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious, I found the error I was having in some regards, although a better explanation would be great.

Basically I was forcing the rails app to use ssl, and for some reason rspec really didn't like that.  Commenting out the ssl line solved all of the issues.